# Search string in UTF-8 Text (body contain Japanese text) file with ADO stream to find match value and line number of match value

Tags: excel, vba, search, text, ado

I have a folder with text files that contains Japanese data (utf-8 text file). I have to search a specific string in those files and find the match. once the match is found I have to copy complete line and its line number (single file can have multiple match). The issue is we can't read UTF-8 data using FSO hence to use ADO stream. I don't know how to read the text file line by line to use `.readline` and how to use search function like `InStr(pos, s, FindThis, vbTextCompare)` which we use with FSO

```
Sub TestR_utf_8()
    Dim st As ADODB.Stream
    Dim sPathname As String, sText As String
    
    sPathname = "c:\tmp\test_utf-8.txt"
    
    ' create a stream object
    Set st = New ADODB.Stream
    
    ' set properties
    st.Charset = "utf-8"
    st.Type = adTypeText
    
    ' open the stream object and load the text
    st.Open
    st.LoadFromFile (sPathname)
    
    ' read 10 characters
    sText = st.ReadText
    
    ' display the characters read
    MsgBox sText
    
    st.Close
    Set st = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not read the entire file into a String (as you're doing) then split the String into an array of Strings (using `Split` and a delimiter eg `vbNewLine`) then loop through the array using `Instr` to look for matches (note that `Instr` is a VBA function, nothing to do with FSO)? ... or is writing the code to do that the problem?

Comment: Be aware MsgBox is not compatible with non-ANSI unicode characters. So please check if your problem is to read the text or to search/compare the sting.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Basic Editor does not support Unicode characters.  Therefore, try the following code, as suggested by @JohnM...

```
Sub TestR_utf_8()

    Dim st As ADODB.Stream
    Dim sPathname As String, sText As String
    Dim linesOfText() As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    sPathname = "c:\tmp\test_utf-8.txt"
    
    ' create a stream object
    Set st = New ADODB.Stream
    
    ' set properties
    st.Charset = "utf-8"
    st.Type = adTypeText
    
    ' open the stream object and load the text
    st.Open
    st.LoadFromFile sPathname
    
    ' read all characters from text stream
    sText = st.ReadText
    
    st.Close
    
    ' split into array of strings
    linesOfText() = Split(sText, vbNewLine)
    
    ' loop through the array of strings using InStr to find a match
    For i = LBound(linesOfText) To UBound(linesOfText)
        If InStr(1, linesOfText(i), ChrW(&H898B), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            'code to copy line, etc
            '
            '
        End If
    Next i
    
    Set st = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Note that you'll need to replace the search term for `InStr` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much @domenic , The above code worked like charm ! , Just have one query , what if the st.readtext have duplicate strings and I want multiple result

Comment: As the code loops through each element of the array containing a line of text, any line that matches the criteria will be copied.